# pyinstaller or any pip packages commands won't work

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

I keep getting this. Also whenever i try to upgrade pip it just stalls and sits on uninstalling forever.
How do i go about fixing this?

```
C:\Users\Jordan>pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e2/c9/0b44b2ea87ba36395483a672fddd07e6a9cb2b8d3c4a28d7ae76c7e7e1e5/PyInstaller-3.5.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  Complete output from command "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe" "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py" get_requires_for_build_wheel C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb_jok3bp:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 207, in <module>
      main()
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 197, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 54, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4q5xlolk\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 146, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4q5xlolk\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 127, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4q5xlolk\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 20, in <module>
      from PyInstaller import __version__ as version, HOMEPATH, PLATFORM
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyInstaller'

  ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe" "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py" get_requires_for_build_wheel C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb_jok3bp" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zhgjxcsa\pyinstaller
You are using pip version 19.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps

Downgrade pip from version 19 to 18.1: `pip install pip==18.1`

Now install PyInstaller using following command: `pip install pyinstaller`

Once the pyinstaller installed you can upgrade your pip again :

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: How long should the uninstall take because it seems to be sitting at uninstalling pip for a while

Comment: I just get ```'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.```